# MultiFieldPanel width in Wagtail and displayed name

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have the following MultiFieldPanel.

```
class TeamRooster(Page):
    staff = StreamField([
        ('staff', CardsBlock(Staff(), icon="plus")),
    ], blank=True)
    content_panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [ StreamFieldPanel('staff') ],
            heading="Staff", classname="col12"
        ),
```

[image]

three times "**Staff**" is too much. I looked in the documentation and tried to delete the names but I have a bug.

And how to change the width of MultiFieldPanel? I tried to add `classname="full"` but it doesn't help me.

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use a MultiFieldPanel? Why not just: content_panels = [StreamFieldPanel('staff'),]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lb-ben-johnston said I changed `content_panels []`

[image]

Thanks @lb-ben-johnston!